# How to convert an image to a float image in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this code:

```
  Mat image00=imread("C:\\Working Dir\\Tests\\TestBlending\\layer0000.jpg");
  Mat image0;
  image00.convertTo(image0,CV_32FC3);
```

But after converting my image to float, the image is blank (all values are zero).

What is wrong with this code and how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be here... How do you check that all values are zero ? Could you give us the output of `printf(" %g %g %g \n",image0.at<Vec3f>(42,42)[0],image0.at<Vec3f>( 42,42)[1],image0.at<Vec3f>( 42,42)[2]);` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try these:

1)
    image00.convertTo(image0, CV_32FC3, 1/255.0);

Mat Image type `CV_8UC3`, value is from 0 to 255. While `CV_32FC3` is between 0.0 and 1.0, hence you have to scale it. If I am not wrong, you receive all zero values as the image consist of mainly BGR values under 125? If it still doesn't work, try this:

2)

```
//CvType
 image00.convertTo(image0, CvType.CV_32FC3, 1/255.0); //with or without scaling, try both
```

Should solve your problem(:

Comment: What's the "OpenCV3" way to do this? (i.e. without using CV_32FC3 but rather something like cv::Mat3f)